# Making a Swift Array conform to a Protocol

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, protocols

Let's say that certain items can appear in a `Feed`, so long as they implement the necessary properties defined by the `Feedable` protocol. Let's also say that the `Photo` object is feed-worthy:

```
extension Photo: Feedable { }
```

Is it possible to say that an `Array` of these photos might also be `Feedable`?

```
extension [Photo] : Feedable
```

Or do I always need some kind of wrapper object, such as a `PhotoAlbum`, to conform to `Feedable`?

**Edit**

To re-iterate, I was curious whether I can make only arrays of `Photo` objects `Feedable`. Not making `Array` of any content type `Feedable`, not making an array of `Feedable`s itself `Feedable` (both of which are offered as solutions below if that's what you need).

In other words, a solution (which I doubt exists) would allow me to define a variable of type `Feedable` with the following outcomes:

```
var feedable: Feedable

//photo is feedable, so this is fine
feedable = Photo() //ok

//arrays of photos are feedable
let photo1 = Photo()
let photo2 = Photo()
feedable = [photo1, photo2]

//arrays of other things are not
feedable = ["no", "dice"] //nope

//even if the contents of an array are themselves Feedable, that's not sufficient. E.g. Video is Feedable, but Array of Videos is not.
let video1 = Video()
let video2 = Video()
feeble = video1 //fine
feedable = [video1, video2] //nope
```

Perhaps [this gist](https://gist.github.com/benpackard/7de27eff770072ca154a2f36283275ac) (which doesn't compile of course) shows the intention more clearly.

Comment: `extension Array where Element: Feedable { ... }`

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm looking to provide a specific implementation of the `Feedable` protocol for an array of `Photo` objects vs arrays of other `Feedable` types. For example, an array of Photos might provide a `feedDescription` that is different to an array of `Video` objects.

Comment: @matt The `Feedable` protocol will provide a different `feedDescription` implementation for a `Photo` vs a group of `Photo`s. E.g. "A photo was added" vs "5 photos were added". Assume I am provided with only the Feed-worthy item (a photo, a video, or a group of either).

Comment: @BenPackard `extension _ArrayType where  Generator.Element == Photo { ... }`

Comment: @matt In my mind its the same reason all of arrays aren't typed `[AnyObject]` - just figured it would be nice to only have arrays of Photos, Videos, and other handled types conform so that I can throw around objects of type Feedable knowing that they will always be able to give me sensible feed descriptions.

Comment: It allows me to say that an array of Photos is Feedable, but an array of Ints is not (by omission). Then a `FeedViewController` can be injected with an array of `Feedable`s. Your approach allows me to pass in *any* array as a `Feedable`, and requires handling non-anticipated array contents (with an empty string, for example).

Comment: @BenPackard i have already posted the solution in my last comment

Comment: I just showed how to extend Photo arrays only

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm in a playground trying to get it to work, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @BenPackard  you are welcome

Comment: @LeoDabus - not having much luck: https://gist.github.com/benpackard/7de27eff770072ca154a2f36283275ac

Comment: you can't override it

Comment: What am I overriding and where? Aren't I just creating an array of `Feedables`, including a `Photo` and a `[Photo]`? O you mean the array can't provide its own implementation of `feedDescription`?

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh ok, so I guess its not a solution in my case then. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you extending the array not the element

Comment: feedables.feedDescription

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow anymore. Perhaps you could fork the Gist and show us what you mean?

Comment: @LeoDabus The point is that `photo` and `photos` should both be added to the `Feedables` array. You are adding `photo` twice. There is also a typo on line 47.

Comment: You still have `let feedables = [photo, photo]` on line 62 when it should be `let feedables = [photo, photos]`. Once you make this correction, I don't think it will compile.

Comment: try like this https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mod0a6z8j4g2h3t/AACZyq0WYbJyiPZt5RwoCAgTa?dl=0

Comment: You have added a property called `photos` to all Arrays. That's not at all what I was aiming for. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve your goal in this way:

Swift 4:

```
protocol Feedable {
    func foo()
}

extension String: Feedable {
    func foo() {    
    }
}

extension Array: Feedable where Element: Feedable {
    func foo() {    
    }
}
// or in more generic way to support Array, Set and other collection types
extension Collection: Feedable where Element: Feedable {
    func foo() {    
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good, but I don't believe it fulfills all the criteria. Specifically, the final example from my code snippet: "Even if the contents of an array are themselves Feedable, that's not sufficient. E.g. Video is Feedable, but Array of Videos is not.
". In your implementation, an array of Strings is Feedable simply because String itself is Feedable.

Answer (score 3):

If there was an array of `Photo` and `Video`,what would you like to be?

1.Every element performs like what they are.

```
extension Array where Element : Feedable {
    func foo() {
        if Element.self == Photo.self {

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

2.The whole array performs as 'Video'.

```
extension Array where Element : Photo {
    func foo() {

    }
}
```

Comment: I would like the former but without having to allow all arrays of any type to be `Feedable`.

Comment: @BenPackard Element is a generic type of an array.And extension with condition will only work when your array confirm to all the conditions.

Comment: @ben-packard the "where" clause in the proposed solutions means that this extension would only apply to Arrays where the element type in the array conforms to the Feedable protocol an not 'all arrays of any type'

Comment: @ScottThompson Which isn't' what I'm asking about. I was wondering about making arrays of Photos Feedable, not making arrays of Feedables Feedable. I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is currently not possible. In my project I have the same issue with a ModelProducer.

```
protocol M: ModelType {}
protocol ModelProducerType {
    associatedtype M: ModelType
    var model: M? { get }
    func produce()
}

struct Test: ModelType {}
class TestProducer: ModelProducerType {
    var model: Test?
    func produce() {
        model = Test()
    }
}
```

I use `ModelType` as a ghost protocol. The problem is I cannot make a model producer that produces multiple `ModelType`s, because of the same reason you discovered. The solution in this case was the following:

```
protocol M: ModelType {}
protocol ModelProducerType {
    associatedtype M: ModelType
    var model: [M] { get }
    func produce()
}

struct Test: ModelType {}
class TestProducer: ModelProducerType {
    var model: [Test] = []
    func produce() {
        model = [Test()]
    }
}
```

This is more flexible from the start. I get rid of the optional variable and single model producers just have one item in the array. Maybe you can use a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array to conform a protocol like this:

```
typealias PhotoArray = [Photo]

extension PhotoArray: Feedable {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers here are almost there for what you want to do. Specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54403035/4691224), with just 1 change it can be restricted to elements of a `type` as opposed to elements confirming to a `protocol`.

## Swift 5.8

```swift
extension Array: Feedable where Element == Photo {
   
}
```

With this extension the code posted on the question shows errors where expected and it ok everywhere else.

[image: Xcode displaying the code from the question]

Answer (score -5):

I didn't try in playground but maybe you can simply make an Array of Feedable:

```
var myPhotosArray = [Feedable]()
```

Then everything implementing the Feedable protocol would be allowed in the Array. If you want only a photo array, You can still subclass your Photo object to make a FeedablePhoto object.

Try this in Playground instead of downvoting without even testing.
Seriously 3 downvotes without any reasons and explanations...

```
import UIKit

protocol Tree: class {
  func grow()
}

class BigTree: Tree {
  internal func grow() {
    print("Big tree growing")
  }
}

class SmallTree: Tree {
  internal func grow() {
    print("Small tree growing")
  }
}

class Car {
  //not a tree
}

var manyTrees = [Tree]()

manyTrees.append(BigTree())
manyTrees.append(SmallTree())
manyTrees.append(Car()) //This makes an error "Car doesn't conform to expected type 'Tree'"
```

Comment: Did you even try before doing a -1 on this post? I tried, it worked.

Comment: I didn't -1 it myself, but this doesn't answer the question at all. I think that is why is it being down-voted.

Comment: From my understanding, it does. Only classes implementing the Feedable protocol can be added to the Array.  question being: "Is it possible to say that an Array of these photos might also be Feedable?" I guess my answer isn't easy to understand and I didn t try this with Swift 3 but Swift 2. Just make a Photo class implement the protocol and that's it.